# Cheese error on Startup

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bits
Logitech webcam C170
Cheese

Opening Cheese there is an error “There was an error playing video from webcam” .
The same camera on the the same PC with Ubutu 16.04 LTS 32 bits on other Hard Disk it works perfectly.

Terminal lsusb output on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits:

```
luis@luis-H81M-DS2:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04d9:1503 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C170
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
luis@luis-H81M-DS2:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Cheese and on Skype I get a black screen but no message. The Audio via the webcam microphone works in Skype and elsewhere. Cheese has worked before and then suddenly does not work. I cannot identify what change I have done that has caused this.